Is it possible to perform a predictive fit of an unknown equation curve with the ROOT framework?
I am a Physics student and I would like to learn how to use the ROOT framework so I am trying to convert the data analyzes of the laboratory experiences of the Radiation-Matter Interaction Laboratory course, which I had performed with Python and R, using the computing power offered by C++ and ROOT.
In short I would like to know if it is possible to perform a predictive fit of an unknown equation curve with ROOT as it is possible to do with predict() offered by R.
In particular I am analyzing the coincidence curve of an experimental setup composed of two scintillators and respective PMTs. What I should get should be something like this:

I tried to make a simple plot of my experimental data points without considering the errors just to show the difference between the two curves if this was not clear.

I've used the TF1 class and the Fit method in various contexts but with the polynomial and Gaussian fits I've tried I can't get a similar result. Surely I can divide the data set into various sections and fit them independently but I would still like to try to see if it is possible to do it directly considering the whole set.

In my opinion, a complete fit on the data is not needed in this case. There are three areas of interest: the coincidence area, the area of signal decrease and the area relating to large delays. For the first you can use a simple linear regression or a polynomial one (see which one fits best but since the area where the two pmt are in coincidence a pol1 should be fine), for the other two areas you can use exponential functions to see the decrease and infinite behavior. So by considering the intersection of the exponential functions with pol1 and finding where they tend to zero you can determine the FWHM. If you want to use a single distribution, try using the sum of two exponentials, one positive and one negative and with the same multiplication factor, or a convolution of two Gaussians, or using two functions like 1/(1+exp(+-x) ).
If you have problems try sharing the code.
If you need further clarification, I also took this exam and most likely with the same professor =)
